# How to implement a C++ stack in several source files as a global variable?

Tags: c++, stack, global-variables

I want to create an LIFO unsigned char stack (maximum 7 elements)

```
stack< unsigned char > s;
```

And use it in several source files as `extern stack` (as a global variable) with C++ standard `<stack>` and `<iostream>` headers. Is it possible? What is the best way to do this job?

How can I create a stack with limited elements (here 7 elements) without tracking the `size()`?

Comment: While it is certainly possible, presence of an extern global variable is usually not a good idea. Instead pass it around properly or create a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

You `extern` a `stack` variable the same way you `extern` any other variable.  In your source files (or a common header file), declare the variable like this:

```cpp
#include <stack>

extern stack< unsigned char > s;
```

And then in *one* of your source files, define the actual variable:

```cpp
stack< unsigned char > s;
```

And no, you can’t limit a `stack` to a max number of elements without checking the `size()` manually before each insertion.

Comment: can't he declare the stack as ```const std::stack<unsigned char>``` and then define it by adding the values like```const std::stack<unsigned char> mystack = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};  ? I mean wouldn't it be limited to seven values then?

Comment: @newbie `extern` would still be needed whether the `stack` is `const` or not: `extern const stack<unsigned char> mystack;` Also, if it is `const` then it can’t be modified after initialized, which kind of defaults the purpose of using a `stack` at all. You may as well just use an array instead.